# Does YUI compressor have support for rewriting relative paths?

Tags: yui-compressor

The problems is that when I run YUI compressor (.NET MsBuild task) the minified css file preserves the same relative paths as in the original ones and given my content structure, this results incorrect paths to images and other resources. Does YUI have an option to configure it to rewrite this URLs? If it doesn't, are there other tools that do could help with this?